# @enabler2dbcrepositories is unable to find my repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I m migrating my database management from blocking to non-blocking(asynchronious) api spring data r2dbc.but there are some problems i need to fix?

HERES WHAT I VE TRIED:
1.changing dependencies OF R2DBC AND other reactor stuffs.
2.changed springboot version of this project you can check my pom.xml below on my previous project (but i ve deleted that project due to some currupt classes) this worked well but now its not working.
3.changed springframework versions several times and i know R2DBC works with 5.2.0.RC2 only but dont know its still not working.
4.run maven clean install but nothing great happen.
below is my code .

heres my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>GamOneY</groupId>
    <artifactId>gamoney.startup</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>GamOneY</name>

<description>PUBG_PC_AUTOMATION_MACHINE</description>

<properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
        <org.springframework.version>5.2.0.RC2</org.springframework.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.M2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>

</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>

</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>

</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-util -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.26</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.simter/simter-r2dbc-ext -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.simter</groupId>
    <artifactId>simter-r2dbc-ext</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-proxy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-proxy</artifactId>

</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>r2dbc-client</artifactId>

</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-autoconfigure-r2dbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0.M1</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot.experimental/spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- <dependency> -->
<!--     <groupId>com.github.mirromutth</groupId> -->
<!--     <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId> -->
<!--     <version>${degraph-check.version}</version> -->
<!-- </dependency> -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-h2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-proxy</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-spi-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0.M8</version>
    <type>pom</type>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>

</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!--  <spring.framework.version>5.2.0.M2</spring.framework.version> -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
  <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
  <version>9.12.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20171018</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mautini</groupId>
    <artifactId>pubg-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mautini</groupId>
    <artifactId>pubg-java-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.17</version>
</dependency>   <!-- ALWAYS NECCESARY IF WE WANT TO USE JSP IN SPRING BOOT -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>  <!-- ALWAYS NECCESARY IF WE WANT TO USE JSP IN SPRING BOOT -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>

</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency> -->
<!--       <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId> -->
<!--       <artifactId>r2dbc-bom</artifactId> -->
<!--       <version>${r2dbc-releasetrain.version}</version> -->
<!--       <type>pom</type> -->
<!--       <scope>import</scope> -->
<!--     </dependency> -->

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>r2dbc-bom</artifactId>
      <version>Arabba-M8</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
<!--            <dependency> -->
<!--                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>${vaadin.version}</version> -->
<!--                <type>pom</type> -->
<!--                <scope>import</scope> -->
<!--            </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Now here my springbootapplication main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
//import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;

import CustomProperties.R2DBCProperties;

@EnableAsync  //Asynchronisely running methods in seperate thread for handling concurrency by user requests
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"Phase3.Tournaments","Phase2.GamersDatabase","Phase4.Results","Phase5.BigGamesData.PUBG","ResultsRepositories","Phase6.ItsAllAboutMoney","Phase7.AwardsAreLove"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages="ResultRepositories")
@EntityScan("ResultsRepositories")
public class GamOneYApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GamOneYApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("I M STARTED");
    }
    @Bean(name="taskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor threadExecutor() {             //BYDEFAULT SPRING WILL USE SIMPLEASYNCTASKEXECUTOR FOR RUNNY @ASYNC METHODS INSEPERATE THREAD WITH DEFAULT THREAD 1 PER REQUEST IF WE DONT PROVIDE THIS TASKEXECUTOR BEAN.
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor tps=new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        tps.setThreadNamePrefix("Another Thread");
        tps.setCorePoolSize(10);                    //will bydefault create 10 threads in thread pool
        tps.setQueueCapacity(100);                  //will hold pending tasts if threads are not available for the 11th request or access 
        tps.setMaxPoolSize(15);                    //if queue got full another 9 extra threads will be created 
        tps.initialize();
    //  tps.setThreadPriority(9);
        return tps;

    }
    @Bean
    public View jsonTemplate() {
            MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
            view.setPrettyPrint(true);
            return view;
    }
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restT() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


}
```

class where i m using my ReactiveCrudRepository(resultrepo1)

```
package Phase4.Results;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import Phase3.Tournaments.*;
import Phase5.BigGamesData.PUBG.PubgStorage;

import ResultsRepositories.*;
import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory;

@Component
public class MatchDataFetcher {
    @Autowired
    private ResultRepo1 repo1; //H2-DATABASE
    @Autowired
    private ResultRepo2 repo2;
    @Autowired
    protected DatabaseClient dc;
    @Autowired
    protected ConnectionFactory conn;
    public  List match1(HttpSession session,Class fetch,String entityName) { //Reusable functions
  //  Sort sort=
   // repo.findAll(sort);  WE WILL FIND OUT WHATS IS SORT CLASS SHORTLY...

       //  Map killers=new HashMap(); we will use it later if we needed
         List l=(List) dc.select().from(fetch).fetch().all().collectList().cache().block();

         System.out.println("heres list baby"+l);

         Iterator it_mp4=l.iterator(); 
         int i=0;
         List<Match1Result> ordered1=(List<Match1Result>) repo1.getSortedResult().collectList().block();
         //List<Match2Result> ordered2=(List<Match2Result>) repo2.getSortedResult().collectList().block();//for second match
         while(it_mp4.hasNext()) {
            // MatchP4 mp4=(MatchP4) it.next(); //FETCHING AND IDENTIFYING JOINED PLAYER GAME RESULT OF PARTICULAR TOURNAMENTS
             MatchP4 mp4=(MatchP4) it_mp4.next();
             if(session.getAttribute("user").equals((String)mp4.getUsername())) { //checking of result wheatha a player has joined or not
                 //System.out.println("Ordered==="+ordered1.get(i).getPubgname());
                 System.out.println(session.getAttribute("user")+"-----"+mp4.getUsername()+"==========YES");
                 return ordered1;




             }
             else {
                 System.out.println("not found");
             }

             i++;
         }
         return null;
       //  MapResult=={avatarname1=chocoTaco, avatarname0=chocoTaco, survived0=3698.114, survived1=3698.114, kills0=34, username1=nikki, kills1=34, username0=nikki}

    }

}
```

my resultrepo1

```
package ResultsRepositories;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Repository
public interface ResultRepo1 extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Match1Result,Integer> {
    @Transactional
      //@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true,flushAutomatically=true)
    @Query(value="UPDATE match1_result SET kills=$1,damage_dealt=$2 WHERE pubgname=$3")
    public Mono<Match1Result> UpdateKills(int kills,float damage,String pubgname);
    @Transactional
    //@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true,flushAutomatically=true)
    @Query(value="UPDATE match1_result SET kills=$1,survivetime=$2 WHERE pubgname=$3")
    public int UpdateKillsMatch2(Integer kills,Double survivetime,String pubgname);
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="SELECT * from match1_result WHERE pubgname=$1")
    public Mono<Match1Result> getLastKills(String pubgname);
    //public List<T> getSortedKills();
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM match1_result ORDER BY kills,damagedealt DESC")
    public Flux<Match1Result> getSortedResult();

}
```

this is my whole process.
i m using spring r2dbc second time but dont know why i m stuck here and i m sure its a dependency problem.
i ve also post this on my github account but its still open waiting there too for response.
please help me fix this.

this is the error i m getting on application startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Field repo1 in Phase4.Results.MatchDataFetcher required a bean of type 'ResultsRepositories.ResultRepo1' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ResultsRepositories.ResultRepo1' in your configuration.
```

i m using spring r2dbc second time but dont know why i m stuck here and i m sure its a dependency problem.
please help me fix this.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Annotation `@EnableR2dbcRepositories` looking for repositories (interfaces) that extends `ReactiveCrudRepository` or `R2dbcRepository` interfaces. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Koziolek/wjug-r2dbc/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/koziolekweb/wrjug/r2dbc/MemberReactiveRepository.java) example.